# Before I accuse somebody... will this ever work well?

Tags: c++

I am looking through some code (ArduPilot, actually) using it as inspiration for my own stuff. Now I think I have found a major bug - but before yelling too loud ;) maybe someonw can help me check if I misunderstood C++.

There is a method (I have simplified it):

```
void GCS_MAVLINK::update(void) {
    // receive new packets
    mavlink_message_t msg;
    mavlink_status_t status;

    // process received bytes
    while (data_available()) {
        uint8_t c = receive_data();
        // Try to get a new message

        if (parse_and_accumulate(c, &msg, &status)) {
            handleMessage(&msg);
        }
    }
}
```

This is called at a regular interval. It reads data from a buffer until exhausted, throws it at an external parse function along with refs to final message and status structs to update by side effect, and every time the parser sees a message completed, the message is consumed.

So far so good. What happens if the buffer runs empty in the middle of a message? OK the rest will probably have arrived to the buffer at next scheduled invocation. But what happens to the locally/stack allocated!!! msg and status variables? As far as I know, they may have been overwritten with all sorts of rubbish from stack usage in the meantime. The stack pointer might even have shifted.

Before I make a fool of myself, can someone help me confirm that there seems to be a major problem here..

Also, if I "fix" it by making the msg and status variables static, they will still be separate for each instance of the class containing the method, right?

Regards
Soren

Comment: What do you mean with the buffer runs empty?  You mean it's full, yet there's still stuff to read from the socket or whatever?

Comment: Depends on what's filling that buffer. Some transports guarantee a message is only delivered complete.

Comment: You are not clear. What buffer? What does `data_available()` do? What does `receive_data()` do? What is the meaning of "buffer runs empty in the middle of a message"?

Comment: Hi, the data arrives asynchronously of the invocation of theGCS_MAVLINK::update method, from a serial interface. So there are no complete message guarantees.

Answer (score 3):

> What happens if the buffer runs empty in the middle of a message?

Presumably, `parse_and_accumulate` is supposed to store the incoming bytes somewhere, separately from the output message parameter, until a message is ready; and only write to that parameter if it is. There's only an error if that function assumes that the message object will be preserved between calls, and without seeing the function there's no way to tell.

> But what happens to the locally/stack allocated!!! msg and status variables?

As you say, they are destroyed when the function exits. *If* `parse_and_accumulate` has used them as persistent storage, then you have a bug since they are not persistent; hopefully, it doesn't, but that assumption is almost certainly what should be fixed if it does.

> Also, if I "fix" it by making the msg and status variables static, they will still be separate for each instance of the class containing the method, right?

Making them `static` won't fix anything; it will probably just cause obscure bugs due to non-reentrancy. If the function you haven't shown us is wrong, then that's what needs fixing.

If you make them `static` (whether as local variables or class members) then there will only be one instance of each. If they did need to be persistent, and associated with the object, then they would have to be non-static class members; but they almost certainly shouldn't be.

Comment: "store the incoming bytes somewhere" -- you'd hope in a data member of `GCS_MAVLINK` or some associated helper object.

Comment: Hi, OK thanks a lot, then I think there really is a bug here. parse_and_accumulate parses the given uint8_t and builds its result data structure into the target of the msg pointer given as argument. Same with status (such as the expected message length).

Answer (score 0):

> Before I make a fool of myself, can someone help me confirm that there seems to be a major problem here..

There may or may not be a problem. It's really impossible to tell with just the code you show.

> What happens if the buffer runs empty in the middle of a message? OK the rest will probably have arrived to the buffer at next scheduled invocation.

Before claiming that there is a bug, you need to make sure that this can actually happen. It doesn't look like the code you show has been written to deal with this, but maybe it doesn't need to?

> Also, if I "fix" it by making the msg and status variables static, they will still be separate for each instance of the class containing the method, right?

No, they won't. They will also make your code non-reentrant and not thread-safe.

Comment: Hi, OK. The data arrives anynchronolysly of the invocation of the code. As I undrestand the system, it really should be able to handle that GCS_MAVLINK::update exhausts the buffer with incoming data, stores a half-built message temporarily and then resumes building the message at a later invocation when more data has arrived to the buffer. I will ask that instead of shouting bug :) and try add some code to detect an instance of the problem happening.. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

OK after looking at the source of parse_and_accumulate again, I now see that it **does** store data across invocations. The argument struct is just used for returning completed messages into..

So my bad - sorry. Thanks for the help!